# Compilation error function PhoenixSwagger.Plug.SwaggerUI.init/1 is undefined Elixir v1.4

Tags: apache-phoenix

Using PhoenixSwagger leads to compilation error
using phoenix swagger

```
# mix file
{:phoenix_swagger, "~> 0.4.0"}


# router.ex
use PhoenixSwagger
..
scope "/api/swagger" do
 forward "/", PhoenixSwagger.Plug.SwaggerUI, otp_app: :http,   swagger_file: "swagger.json"
end


`== Compilation error on file web/router.ex ==
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function  PhoenixSwagger.Plug.SwaggerUI.init/1 is undefined (module   PhoenixSwagger.Plug.SwaggerUI is not available`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem.

Update to latest `phoenix_swagger` and define it that way:

`forward "/", PhoenixSwagger.Plug.SwaggerUI, otp_app: :myapp, swagger_file: "swagger.json", opts: [disable_validator: true]`